# What's the little number on the top of a number w/ unit?

Tags: phrase-requests, mathematics

I want to ask what is the little numbers on top/over any random number? For example, 75 in² and 125 ft<sup>3</sup>. What is it called and what does it mean is my question. I couldn't find anything online since I don't know what it is called.

Comment: Note that 'random number' has a special meaning in computing and mathematics. I would use 'arbitrary number' ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not English.

Comment: I'd be with Janus, 100%, if it was clear what you meant.

Are you asking about the mathematical value of that little number on the top, or the typographical description?

Either way, this isn't about general English, so I'm back with Janus.

Comment: I think [exponent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exponent) will help you more than *superscript*.

Comment: "This tag is for questions about the usage and meaning of mathematical terminology and the **names for mathematical entities in English.**" - Mathematics tag description.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK also, the exponents are not on the numbers, they're on the units, at least in the examples OP has given.

Comment: Can you give a link to where you see this? I have absolutely _no_ idea what '3' you're talking about.

Comment: @PhilSweet Arguably “what is it called” would be on-topic, but “what does it mean” (meaning, as asked here, “what does adding a superscript number after a unit mean/do?”) definitely isn’t. I doubt that would be considered on-topic even on [mathematics.se] where it would theoretically belong.

Comment: While square and cubic inches in your example are most likely a superscript number can also be used as an anchor for a footnote (end page or end of document)

Comment: Is it just me or is there no "little 3 on top" (or any "3" except in that phrase) anywhere in the question..?!

Comment: The little three is being described as the exponent on the "ft", as in $\text{ft}^3$.  I take that the OP does not know how to typeset it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In terms of formatting, numbers and letters that appear in the top half of a line are in *superscript*. Similarly, numbers in the bottom half of a line would be called *subscript*. "Super" and "sub" describe their position over or under the main text.

In your examples, these superscript numbers stand for a mathematical exponent or power as applied to a unit of measurement. If I were reading it out loud, I might say "seventy-five inches squared," or (more clearly) "seventy-five square inches." It means that I am talking about a unit of distance extending in two dimensions. It's a measurement of surface area, just like houses can be measured in square feet (ft<sup>2</sup>) and land can be measured in square miles (mi<sup>2</sup>). The cubic version (in<sup>3</sup>) would refer to a measurement across three dimensions, or a measurement of volume.

Other measurements can also be squared or cubed, especially when doing calculations in STEM fields, but square inches/feet/miles are the most common examples of this in the US.

Comment: This is a good point: _superscript_ is a typographic term, whereas _exponent_ and _power_ describe the mathematical usage. It's anybody's guess which one OP had in mind.

Comment: Of course you could be really evil and mean "75 inches, see footnote two". Then it would be a superscript but not an exponent.

Comment: 75 inches square is not the same as 75 square inches.

Comment: I somehow missed your *exponent* answer. If you want, I'll just add my answer to the bottom of yours for a reference and delete my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The general term for a number (or other text) written like this is **[superscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscript_and_superscript)**.

The term in<sup>2</sup> refers to [square inches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_inch), which is the amount of area in a square with sides an inch in length.

Likewise, if it were in<sup>3</sup>, it would be referring to [cubic inches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_inch), which is the amount of volume in a cube with side lengths of an inch.

Answer (score 3):

**Exponent**

> 3.6 Derived Units— Derived units are formed by combining base units according to the algebraic relations linking
>   the corresponding quantities. Symbols for derived units are obtained by means of mathematical signs for
>   multiplication, division, and the use of **exponents**. For example, the SI unit for speed is the meter per second
>   (m/s or m·s<sup>–1</sup> and that for density is kilogram per cubic meter kg/m<sup>3</sup>
>    or kg·m<sup>–3</sup>). Most derived units have only
>   their composite names, such as meter per second for speed or velocity. Others have special names, such as
>   newton (N), joule (J), watt (W), and pascal (Pa), given to SI units of force, energy, power, and pressure (or
>   stress), respectively.

SAE Technical Standards Board: Rules for SAE Use of SI (Metric) Units, Rev May 1999.
https://www.sae.org/standardsdev/tsb/tsb003.pdf